# How to make result arrangement for the variable?

Tags: variable

I was calculating equations,

```
p2 := 1 e + r M1^2
p1 := 1 + r M2^2
p2/p1/.M2-> Sqrt[((r - 1)/(2 r))]
Simplify@%/.e -> 0
```

where e : to remove by approximation that M1 is close to infinite(term of M1 is very large then other term, since neglect other term)

This results is

```
(2 M1^2 r)/(1 + r)
```

I want to make result as

```
(2 r)/(1 + r) *  M1^2
```

And why these result cannot be simple form

```
T2 := 1 ϵ + (r - 1)/2 M1^2
T1 := 1 + (r - 1)/2 M2^2
ρ2 := M1 Sqrt[T1]
ρ1 := M2 Sqrt[T2]
$Assumtions = r > 0;
$Assumtions = M1 > 1;
ρ2/ρ1 // Refine // FullSimplify
% /. M2 -> Sqrt[(r - 1)/(2 r)]
% /. ϵ -> 0 // Simplify
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
p2 := 1 e + r M1^2
p1 := 1 + r M2^2
p2/p1 /. M2 -> Sqrt[((r - 1)/(2 r))]
expr = Simplify@% /. e -> 0
```

[image]

If you want a non-standard (to Mathematica) form you have to force it

```
Inactive[Times][Coefficient[expr, M1^2], M1^2]
```

[image]

You misspelled `$Assumptions`

```
T2 := 1 ϵ + (r - 1)/2 M1^2
T1 := 1 + (r - 1)/2 M2^2
ρ2 := M1 Sqrt[T1]
ρ1 := M2 Sqrt[T2]
$Assumptions = {r > 0, M1 > 1};
ρ2/ρ1 // FullSimplify (* Refine is unnecessary *)
% /. M2 -> Sqrt[(r - 1)/(2 r)]
% /. ϵ -> 0 // Simplify
```

[image]